# What is a tinytext in php and what´s the difference between tinytext and string?

Tags: c#, php, mysql, string, int64

I got a debug report on a site written in php (debug information of an [easydutyplan](http://easydutyplan.de/) parser) and I saw

> [rowParam] => Array
>                           (
>                               [0] => BIGINT
>                               [1] => BIGINT
>                               [2] => INT
>                               [3] => TINYTEXT
>                               [4] => TINYTEXT
>                               [5] => TINYTEXT
>                           )

What is the difference between a tinytext and a string? And is bigint the same as an Int64 in C#?

Comment: Can it be that the `tinytext` is related to a field in the database?
I am not familier with `tinytext` in PHP , in MYSQL yes.

Comment: I´m not sure but it could be so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These actually have nothing to do with PHP.  They are MySQL data types.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

Tinytext is used as a field type to reserve L + 1 bytes, where L < 2 to the 8th.

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not have these data types. These look like database data types. If you use the normal php debug: `var_dump($your_variable);` you can see the PHP data types for your structure.

here's a reference to [php's data types](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.php)